# What is the relation between crystals and crystal bases?

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-groups

Kashiwara introduced the concept of crystal bases (Lusztig introduced canonical basis), see for example the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_base). Kashiwara also introduces the concept of [crystals](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kenkyubu/kashiwara/on-crystal.pdf) (Section 7).

What is the relation between crystals and crystal bases? Thank you very much.

Comment: These are comments, not answers. I'll note that I often hear the terms "crystal" and "crystal base" referred to interchangeably, so be careful there. A crystal basis in the quantum group sense is very linear-algebraic, and is some kind of very nice choice of lattice and basis inside a representation of that quantum group. The basis then satisfies some nice combinatorial properties. I guess you could say the notion of "crystal" kind of divorces this from the quantum group, and considers crystals as abstract directed edge-coloured graphs satisfying some properties.